# Implying correlation of a two random variables from their correlations with a third random variable- $E[YZ]$ given $E[XY]$ and $E[XZ]$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance, correlation

Given we have
1.) $E[XY], E[XZ]$
2.) $E[X]$, and $E[X^2]$ for all three variables.

**Q:** How do we arrive at $E[YZ]$?

A follow up $Q:$, if you decide that it is not possible, is that what information is needed to arrive at that number?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your "1.)" should have $E[XZ]$ instead of $E[YZ]$.

Comment: The $3\times3$ covariance matrix of $(X,Y,Z)$ must be positive semidefinite.  Your known constraints specify all matrix entries except for the two entries for $E[YZ]=E[ZY]$. There is a convex set of values for them that makes the matrix psd.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks. Edited

Comment: @kimchilover that's an interesting idea. I wonder how broad that is set. I'll look into it